Cubic equations whose absolute values of roots form a triangle?
A cubic equation has three roots and with three numbers it is natural to ask if their absolute values form the sides of a triangle i.e. satisfy the triangle inequality. I observed that if the coefficient of a cubic equation are all positive then we can answer this question without actually calculating the roots. Assume that the coefficients of
$$
f(x) = a_3x^3 + a_2x^2 + a_1x + a_0 = 0
$$
are positive. WLOG we can assume that the largest coefficient is $1$ and all other are in the interval $(0,1]$. We have four cases depending on weather the coefficient of $x^n, n = 0,1,2,3$ is $1$.
Experimental observations

If $\frac{1}{2} \le a_1,a_2,a_3 \le 1$ then the absolute values of the roots of the equation $a_3x^3 + a_2x^2 + a_1x + 1 = 0$ form a triangle.
If $\frac{1}{3} \le a_0,a_2,a_3 \le 1$ then the absolute values of the roots of the equation $a_3x^3 + a_2x^2 + x + a_0 = 0$ form a triangle.
If $\alpha_2 \le a_0,a_1,a_3 \le 1$ where $\displaystyle \alpha_2 \gtrsim \frac{2\cdot 2^{2/3}}{2 + 3\cdot 2^{1/3}}$ is a constant then the absolute values of the roots of the equation $a_3x^3 + x^2 + a_1x + a_0 = 0$ form a triangle.
If $\frac{1}{4} \le a_0,a_1,a_2 \le 1$ the absolute values of the roots of the equation $x^3 + a_2x^2 + a_1x + a_0 = 0$ form a triangle.

Can these be proved or disproved?

Are you assuming real coefficients? For example the absolute values of coefficients in $x^3+i x^2 + \frac{i}{2}x + i/4$ satisfy the conditions for case 2 but the absolute values of the roots are approx. 0.486, 0.432 and 1.19.

Yes the coefficients are real and bounded by the inequalities / intervals mentioned in the post.

If the coefficients of the polynomial are real numbers, then two of the three complex solutions are conjugated to each other, since
$$conj(x^3+a_2x^2+a_1x+a_0)=conj(x)^3+a_2conj(x^2)+a_1conj(x)+a_0=0$$
This means that one of the three solutions is a real number $x_0$ and the remain two are conjugated to each other: $x_1=a+ib, x_2=a-ib$.
In particular, the set of solutions $\{x_0,x_1,x_2\}$ forms either an isosceles triangle or it is a segment if $x_0=a$ is the middle point of $\vec{x_1x_2}$.
If we have $x_0,x_1,x_2$ are the solution of a polynomial of degree three, then the polynomial can be constructed as
$$(x-x_0)(x-x_1)(x-x_2)=0 \implies x^3-(x_0+x_1+x_2)x^2+(x_0x_1+x_0x_2+x_1x_2)x-x_0x_1x_2=0$$
Hence
$$ a_2=-(x_0+x_1+x_2) \qquad a_1=x_0x_1+x_0x_2+x_1x_2 \qquad a_0=-x_0x_1x_2.  $$
In our specific case we have
$$ a_2=-(x_0+2a) \qquad a_1=2x_0a+a^2+b^2 \qquad a_0=-x_0(a^2+b^2)$$
Let us assume our roots have absolute values satisfying triangle inequalities, that can be summarised requiring that
$$ 2\sqrt{a^2+b^2}\geq \vert x_0\vert $$
Now we consider $a_2, a_1, a_0$ as real functions written in function of $x_0, a,b$. Since WLOG we can assume $\vert a_i\vert \leq 1$ and these functions are continuous and defined on the compact and connected subset $a_i^{-1}([0,1])\cup \{2\sqrt{a^2+b^2}\geq \vert x_0\vert\}$, then their image is a closed interval and the function admits maximum and minimum values. You can use Langrange multiplier theorem to determine that intervals $[c_i,d_i]$, one for each function $a_i$. Thus at the end you will have that your polynomial will have three roots for which their absolute value satisfy your triangle inequality condition if and only if
$$ a_2\in [c_2,d_2], \qquad a_1\in [c_1,d_1], \qquad a_0\in [c_0,d_0].$$
Can you find these values $c_i, d_i$?

@ Fedrico - Shoun't it be $2\sqrt{a^2+b^2}\geq \vert x_0\vert$

The solutions of a cubic equation can be one real number plus two conjugate complex numbers, or three real numbers. Does you analysis cover the second case as well?

Yeah thank you, you are right, I just thought on this. I will add the second case in the next days :)

@ Fedrico - Also shouldn't it be $a_0=-x_0(a^2+b^2)$
